# Worst-case running time of divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

I am a student who is taking the programming class data structures and algorithms and I am in need of help with a exam question I cant seem to get a grip off.

Here is the problem:

*Consider the following algorithm* **func** *on a given array A = {a1, a2, ..., an}:*

- If n = 1, then return.
- If a1 > an, then exchange a1 and an.
- Run **func** on {a1, a2, ... ,a2n/3}.
- Run **func** on {an/3, a(n/3)+1, ... ,an}.
- Run **func** on {a1, a2, ... ,a2n/3}.

*Give a recurrence for the worst-case running time of this algorithm.*

Here is a link to an image of the assignment if my explanation wasnt clear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3qNG.png

I understand that it is a divide and conquer problem but Im having a hard time to figure out how to solve it.

Thank you :)

Comment: So, the number of operations as a function of length can be expressed by the recurrence `T(n) = 3 T(2n/3) + 1`, with base case `T(1) = 1`. Is that enough to get you going?

Comment: Hmm... sort of! But I dont really understand how {an/3, a(n/3)+1, ... ,an} becomes T(2n/3)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If a1 > an, then exchange a1 and an.
```

this is a constant operation - so O(1)

```
Run func on {a1, a2, ... ,a2n/3}.
```

You invoke the array recursively on 2n/3 of it, so T(2n/3)

```
Run func on {an/3, a(n/3)+1, ... ,an}.
Run func on {a1, a2, ... ,a2n/3}.
```

Similar to the above, each one is T(2n/3)

this gives you total of `T(n) = 3T(2n/3) + O(1)`, and `T(1) = O(1)`.

Now, we can get a big O notation, using [master theorem case 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_1):

```
log_{3/2}(3) ~= 2.7
```

O(1) is in `O(n^2.7)`, so we can use the case, and get that `T(n)` is in

```
Theta(n^log_{3/2}(3)) ~= Theta(n^2.7)
```

Comment: Wow, thats more advanced than I thougt it would be! Dont think we have been working with the master theorem case at all. Thank you for your help though!
Could you explain why {an/3, a(n/3)+1, ... ,an} becomes T(2n/3)?

Comment: Because it contains 2n/3 of the elements, those with index `n/3,n/3+1 , ..., n-1,n`, and you invoke the function recursively on those 2n/3 elements.

Comment: Okey thank you! 
So the worst case running time of this algorithm is Theta(n^2.7)?
Will have to read up more on the master theorem case.

Comment: *approximately* Theta(n^2.7), it is actually `Theta(n^log_{3/2}(3))`. This is also the average case of the algorithm.